# "Search for app in the Store?" prompt when opening .exe files

Tags: windows-10

I just did a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro 1909. Now, whenever I try to open an .exe file I get this popup:

[image]

This doesn't happen when launching an installed application. Only if opening an .exe directly. If I hit "No" the program then launches like normal. If I hit "Yes" the Store never opens and the program launches like normal as well.

I believe this is just happening for unsigned applications. On another Windows PC these same files prompt me with the Windows Defender SmartScreen warning where I have to click "Run Anyway" to get the app to run. Could it be that something from Windows Defender is missing?

Edit: I disabled "Check apps and files" in the Windows Security settings and the popup stopped afterwards. Once I set it back to "Warn" they came back. Seems like a strong indication that something is wrong with Defender/SmartScreen.

Comment: Your file extensions are incorrect.  Since it’s a fresh install I suggest a full reinstall